# Use of Present Perfect Simple / Present Perfect Continuous (Progressive) when stopping an activity

Tags: tense

I am confused about the use of present perfect simple/present perfect continuous at a time when the person has decided to stop the activity.

For instance, which one of the two sentences is correct.

> We have been studying for two hours, but now we should take a break.

> We have studied for two hours, but now we should take a break.

Is it possible that both the sentences are correct? If so, do they mean the same thing?

PS. I have read a lot of posts at ELL about the correct use of present perfect and perfect continuous tense. But I am still confused about the correct usage in this context. I hope someone **expert** in English grammar can answer the question.

Comment: Both are idiomatic and mean the same, but I would say the first sounds more natural.

Answer (score 1):

> We have been studying for two hours, **so** now we should take a break.

gives a better sense that the break would occur immediately after the two hour period.

Also, I would use "so", not "but". There are no contrasting phrases, just a progression of events.